# How does one identify if python script was run for the first time?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I've been wondering if there's any way to find out if a python script was run for the first time.

Let's suppose I have this simple program:

```
import random
import string
from uuid import getnode


def get_mac():
    return getnode()


def generate_unique_id():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(20))


def main():
    get_mac()
    generate_unique_id()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'd like to know if there's any way to find / count the number of times a program is being run on a Windows machine.

Any other workarounds are welcome.

Comment: The only way is to keep a count yourself, say by writing a text file or a registry entry.

Comment: You could use standard logging library to log all the iterations https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html

Comment: @DanielRoseman would you mind giving a short example based on a text file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to keep track of all the times your software was run**

There really is no way without writing to a file every time you start, and then appending to this file. So that way, you'd simply go look up the file to keep track of your program.

**If you want to see when the last time your software was compiled**

I guess another thing you could technically do is check the date of your generated compiled python bytecodes, but this would only tell you the last time your program executed, not the first time or the total number of times.

[This link shows you how to check for the creation/modification/update times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)
.

Comment: I'm aware of all of these but they are not helping me at all. Thanks for the answer anyway. (I'm talking about the last part of your answer)

Comment: .pyc files are only created for imported modules, not scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple idea to count the number of runs of a specified script:

```
def RunCounter(filename, reset=False):

    f = open("run_counter_{}.txt".format(filename), "a+")   #"a+" stands for Append and Read
    
if reset == True:    # if you wish to reset the counting
        f.truncate(0)

    f.seek(0)        
    lines = f.readlines()
    if len(lines) == 0:    #if the file is empty
        f.write("0")
        f.seek(0)
        lines = f.readlines()
    else:
        f.write("\n1")     #if there is already a non-zero number of lines
        f.seek(0)
        lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    
    return len(lines)
```

Basically, this script creates a text file associated to a specified script, opens it, reads it and writes "1" in the first available line. If the file does not exist, it creates a new one. If the existing file is empty, it writes "0" in the first line. You can always reset the counting by setting the argument `reset=False` .

In principle, this works for every script: just change the argument `filename` to the name of the file you wish to count the runs of. In this case, the text file is "run_counter_default.txt":

```
>>> print(RunCounter("default", reset=True))
1
>>> print(RunCounter("default", reset=False))
2
>>> print(RunCounter("default", reset=False))
3
>>> print(RunCounter("default", reset=True))
1
```

And so on.

Hope this helps.